# Asking for User Consent in Symfony Form doesn't submit

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, form-submit

this is my first post on stackoverflow !

I have this problem in my Controller method. 
I would like to ask the User if he wants to add something that he searched for and doesn't exist to the database. But when I ask for his consent, the form I made doesn't submit. I'm not sure if I'm clear or not but here's my 2 forms first and the controller function.

The first form I use :

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MachineOSType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name',TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom de l\'OS'
            ])
            ->add('version',TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Version de l\'OS',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('Valider',SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-block form-rounded btn-success']
            ])
    ;
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => null
    ]);
}
}
```

The Second form asking for consent, just a yes/no (oui/non)

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ValidationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('reponse',ChoiceType::class,[
                    'label' => ' Choix ',
                    'choices'=> [
                        'Oui' => 1,
                        'Non' => 0,
                    ],
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'radio-inline text-center '],
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'text-center']
                ])
            ->add('Valider',SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-success form-rounded']
            ])
    ;
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => null
    ]);
}
}
```

The Controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/OS/add", name="os_machine_add_form", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function os_machine_add_form(Machine $machine, Request $request, Request $request2, OperatingSystemRepository $osr)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(MachineOSType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $nomOS = $form["name"]->getData();
        $verOS = $form["version"]->getData();
        $fullOS = [
            'nomOS' => $nomOS,
            'verOS' => $verOS
        ];
        if ($verOS != null) {
            $OS = $osr->findBy([
                'name' => $nomOS,
                'version' => $verOS,
            ]);
            $size = count($OS);
            if ($size == 0) {
                $form2 = $this->createForm(ValidationType::class);
                $form2->handleRequest($request2);
                if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {
                    if ($form2["reponse"]->getData() == 1) {
                        $newOS = new OperatingSystem();
                        $newOS->setName($nomOS);
                        $newOS->setVersion($verOS);
                        $em->persist($newOS);
                        $em->flush();
                    } 
                }
                return $this->render('machine/os_add.html.twig', [
                    'fullos' => $fullOS,
                    'os' => $OS,
                    'machine' => $machine,
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'form2' => $form2->createView(),
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('machine/os_add.html.twig', [
        'machine' => $machine,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Here is what I get when I submit something that doesn't exist in the database:
[Image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZNmd.png)
but when I click on "Valider" It doesn't create a new object.

If you have any suggestions, or any other way of doing that, I'm taking it, I'm kinda new to Symfony so :)

Thank you for reading.

**EDIT :**

I dropped out the idea of using a validation form. I created another function that I called in an a tag

The function :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{id}/user/validate/OS/{nomOS}/{verOS}", name="user_validate")
 */

 public function userValidate(Machine $machine,$nomOS, $verOS) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $newOS = new OperatingSystem;
    $newOS->setName($nomOS);
    $newOS->setVersion($verOS);
    $em->persist($newOS);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('machine_show', ['id' => $machine->getId()]);

}
```

And in the twig :

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <a href="{{path('user_validate'{id:machine.id,nomOS:fullos.nomOS,verOS:fullos.verOS})}}" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> Oui </a>
 </div>
```

I'm not really sure if it's clean or secure, but that'll do for now.

Comment: You need a second controller action to handle the second form. When you submit `$form2`, `os_machine_add_form()` is executed and the condition `$form->isSubmitted()` is false, since the first form isn't submitted

Comment: by controller action, you mean another function ? Like 
/**
*@Route("/validation", name="validate")
*/
public function validate () {
//...
}

Answer (score 0):

Two forms in one action this is not a best practice here you have $request and $request2 you are passing the same argument into your action and your trying to handle request of your form so your form1 receive all formData of the two form so it wont be valid unless you allow extra data

Comment: So do you have any idea how I can ask for user consent to create a new Operating System object and add it to the database ?

Comment: Add public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
        $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        )
    );
} So you can allow extra field even do it's not related to your form you need to add it in both form so it's still valid

Comment: I tried , it stills doesnt work. When I click on the second validate it just doesn't persist the new Operating System